# buildFor in Java and 2 constructors inside a class

Tags: java

Hello I have created a class in which there is 2 constructor like this :

```
public class Test {
    int speed;
    int id;
    int height = 0;
    Test(final int speed, final int id, final int height) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.id = id;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public Test buildFor(final int speed, final int id) {
        return new Test(speed, id, 5);
    }
    public void show() {
        System.out.println(this.speed);
        System.out.println(this.id);
        System.out.println(this.height);
    }
}
```

and In the main I try to create an Object like this :

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    Test testObject = new Test(4,4);
    testObject.show();
}
```

but it fails in this line :  **`Test testObject = new Test(4,4)`**;
What does the **BuildFor** and what's wrong with this code ?

Comment: There is only one constructor in this class. Method `buildFor` looks a bit like a static factory method, only it is not `static`.

Comment: It works now ! thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 1):

`buildFor` is a method, not a constructor. So you cannot invoke that method like a constructor with the `new` keyword.

It looks like you are trying to chain your constructors.

The correct approach to do that would be:

```
public Test(final int speed, final int id) {
    this(speed, id, 5);
}
```

This is a constructor with 2 arguments that internally calls the other constructor with 3 arguments passing the 2 arguments it received along and a default value of 5 for the last argument.

Comment: Or BuildFor is meant to be static ...

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because you are passing in two parameters into your constructor instead of three. You can create another constructor for this circumstance:

```
public class Test {
    int speed;
    int id;
    int height = 0;
    Test(final int speed, final int id, final int height) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.id = id;
        this.height = height;
    }
    Test(final int speed, final int id) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Test buildFor(final int speed, final int id) {
        return new Test(speed, id, 5);
    }
    public void show() {
        System.out.println(
            this.speed
        );
        System.out.println(
            this.id
        );
        System.out.println(
            this.height
        );
    }
}
```

Additionally, the method buildFor() is not a constructor, so if you want it to run you have to call it manually.

I hope this helped! Let me know if you have any other questions/clarifications.